# How to vizualize OpenCV imshow() window on a VPS server?

Tags: python, user-interface, visual-studio-code, vps, vscode-remote

I am running this code on my distant vps server:

```
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('yolov5nu.pt')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Bowling1.mp4')
while cap.isOpened():
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if success:
        results = model(frame)
        annotated_frame = results[0].plot()
        cv2.imshow("YOLOv5 Inference", annotated_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But then I get:

```
[W NNPACK.cpp:51] Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware.
0: 384x640 (no detections), 90.2ms
Speed: 2.2ms preprocess, 90.2ms inference, 0.4ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/root/anaconda3/envs/yolo5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

When I simply double click on the video 'Bowlin1.mp4' it displays in VSCode and I can read it:

[image]

Can't visualize the VideoCapture the same way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you double-click on a video file on your own computer, it is played back on your own computer. When you double-click on that video file on your server, VSCode **downloads** it and then displays it for you, on your own computer.

Your own computer is distinct from any other computer on the internet. A VPS is a **server on the internet**. It's not identical to your own computer that you sit in front of.

That server on the internet does not have a graphics card or a display. It can't display any graphics. Even if it could, VSCode can't bring any graphical interfaces from that remote computer onto your own local computer.

`imshow()` is like any other GUI on a computer. it only shows on the computer itself, nowhere else. That computer is a server on the internet, not in your room.

You will never be able to see any `imshow()` windows when you run code on a remote computer.

Comment: then I need a way to have imshow to connect to VLC from distant server to my computer

Comment: ok cool, a lot of people are asking about that, so there's a lot of existing questions, and answers, on that.